# Is there an equivalent to disabling glitch-free (tsched=0) for Pipewire?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, streaming, pipewire

Using Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS. Just as a note, I don't have a lot of Linux knowledge and I'm only here because I can't install another OS on my computer, so I may not be the brightest.

I was using PulseAudio previously, and during that time period, things were mostly fine, except for Discord streams. Aside from the no audio during streaming, I noticed that when watching other people's streams, the audio always lagged behind the stream video. The audio would fall in and out of sync with the stream and constantly stutter. I was able to fix this by looking in /etc/pulse/default.pa, and adding "tsched=0" to the end of the line "load-module module-udev-detect."

Recently I've switched to PipeWire in order to use the "discord-screenaudio" app so that I could stream with audio. However, regardless of whether I use that app or the regular Discord app, I am *again* having the issue where audio will lag behind other people's streams. Any idea how I could fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Im on 22.10 which have pipewire default and also have lag

Now I am run on every startup

```
 systemctl --user unmask pulseaudio
```

and

```
 systemctl --user --now enable pulseaudio.{socket,service}
```

after this I toggle sounds outputs if there is no or garbled sound

Comment: I guess that works temporarily but I'll have to swap between the two constantly depending on if I want to stream something or watch a stream. Not particularly ideal